# Censored data when censoring time is uneven

Tags: machine-learning, survival, censoring

I have a data set relating to credit defaults. The data set contains around 100 predictors (some categorical and some numeric). I am interested in predicting the time to default, if the person ever defaults. The term of the loan is 36 months, so a person could default at months 1-36, or never.

The problem is for one segment of the data, I have 36 months of information, another segment of the data I have 24 months of information and another segment I have only 12 months of information.

I realize that this is a censored data set, but my specific questions are:

1. How does the fact that the time of censoring is different for different segments of the data (12 months, 24 months, 36 months) affect the analysis? In the examples of censored data analysis I have read, the time of censoring is always the same. For example, a medical study that ended at month X, so all the data is right censored at this time.
2. If I am solely interested in maximizing my predictive power (according to some metric; I am aware of the dangers of data dredging) what are the best techniques for evaluating a dataset like this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the usual models where censoring arises (like survival models), there's generally no requirement for censoring to be simultaneous.